# how to check response header from apache

Tags: java, apache

When a request is coming in, it goes through apache sever before going to application server written in tomcat.  In most cases, I can set the response header from apache server to return a certain response header like x-frame-options.  However, depending on the page and requester, I would like to remove this x-frame-options in the apache layer.
So far, I tried following two options, but both did not work.

1. apache always set the header to generic, but application server override it to something else based on the condition.

   apache Httpd.conf:  Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

   Java Code:  response.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "DENY");
2. application server set to something else then apache to check the header before setting to generic.

   Java Code:  response.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "DENY");

   apache httpd.conf: RequestHeader set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" env=no_my_header

I don't know what to do at this point.  If anyone has any idea, I would appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you call the "requester" here?

Comment: Requester is not important here.  For instance, if the page is iframed by approved site, I would like to remove x-frame-options, so that they can iframe the pages.  If not, I would keep the x-frame-options to block.